# Is my save data on a GBA cartridge removed if I change the battery?

Tags: game-boy-advance

Recently my battery of Pokemon Ruby died and I was thinking if I am going to replace the battery will my save be deleted too? I was looking into this but could not find any anwsers, I found one for the pre gameboy advance games but what is the best option with GBA games?.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Generally the battery in a cartridge's only purpose is to maintain the save data. If that is dead (and I am not sure how you would know this with out your save data being missing) then chances are your save data is gone. However, I am not 100% sure on the inner workings of the GBA cartridges so until someone comes up with referenced confirmation, this is just left as a comment.

Comment: Well my game said that the battery has run dry. And I am not missing anything yet, So I want to change it but I am not sure if this affects my days. Well thanks for your response

Comment: according to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221224/do-gba-cartridge-batteries-run-dry-after-some-time) you should be fine the ruby cartridge only uses the battery for the time.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if this is the same for firered and leaf green?

Comment: [There already is an answer that fits what you're asking](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221224/do-gba-cartridge-batteries-run-dry-after-some-time); therefore I think there is no reason to answer this question. This question will be marked as a duplicate, unless you are having a different problem.

Comment: That is a question asking if batteries run dry after some time? I have checked that question. And I could not find the specific answer. My question is specific to pokémon only so I shall edit it like that.

Comment: this question is not a duplicate of the linked question and would not be associated to any user searching for details about what the error they recieved was implying....as a side note I would advise anyone that if they are in such a situation that they wish to replace a low battery but avoid loosing data associated with it they could attempt to make a temporary connection to the power rails with a spare battery of the same type while the user swapped the dying cell with a new one.

Comment: That's indeed a good idea, it's what I did as well and no data-loss, so just to be sure it's a good method